# How to print out enum name from a method

Tags: java

i'm trying to build a method that will print out an enum when my switch statement finds an appropriate match, below is my attempt. I could do this by adding a `System.out.println("")` inside every of the case statments, however i feel like there is a better way of doing this.

```
enum  animals
{
    ANIMAL_CAT,
    ANIMAL_DOG,
    ANIMAL_SNAKE,
}

public static animals getAnimal(char ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case 'C':
            return animals.ANIMAL_CAT;
        case 'D':
            return  animals.ANIMAL_DOG;
        case 'S':
            return animals.ANIMAL_SNAKE;
    }

    return animals;

}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    getAnimal('C'); // output: ANIMAL_CAT
    getAnimal('D'); // etc
    getAnimal('S');
}
```

Comment: You can't,in Java  the name given to the enum is a constant, no constant names are available.  Try using a map, then you can have literal strings to unique identify each value.

Comment: @SPlatten He could create a constructor and assign String literal to each enum key.

Comment: @SPlatten - sure you can:  calling [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString()) on a value of an enum constant returns the name of the enum constant.

Comment: Check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-customized-value-java/

Answer (score 1):

The following code works as you intended,

```
class sample{
    enum  animals
    {
        ANIMAL_CAT,
        ANIMAL_DOG,
        ANIMAL_SNAKE,
        NO_ANIMAL
    }

    public static animals getAnimal(char ch)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'C':
                return animals.ANIMAL_CAT;
            case 'D':
                return  animals.ANIMAL_DOG;
            case 'S':
                return animals.ANIMAL_SNAKE;
            default:
                return animals.NO_ANIMAL;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getAnimal('C')); // output: ANIMAL_CAT
        System.out.println(getAnimal('D')); // etc
        System.out.println(getAnimal('S'));
    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
ANIMAL_CAT
ANIMAL_DOG
ANIMAL_SNAKE
```

Answer (score 0):

enum are still classes, and should be treated as such. Thus, give the Animals class the capability it needs to do what you want

```
enum Animals {
        ANIMAL_CAT('C'), ANIMAL_DOG('D'), ANIMAL_SNAKE('S');
    private final char internalValue;

    private Animals(final char internalValue) {
        this.internalValue = internalValue;
    }

    public static Optional<Animals> fromInternalValue(final char ch) {
        return Arrays.stream(Animals.values()).filter(candidate -> candidate.internalValue == ch).findFirst();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Animals.fromInternalValue('C').ifPresent(Animals::print);
    Animals.fromInternalValue('D').ifPresent(Animals::print);
    Animals.fromInternalValue('S').ifPresent(Animals::print);
}
```

Comment: Small suggestion, keep a `private` copy of `Animals.values()` stored inside the enum. Else everytime `fromInternalValue()` is called a new copy of `Animals.values()` is created

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the name from the Enum-Object:
getAnimals("XYZ").name();